# Route the default URL trailed with a named arg

Tags: cakephp, routes, named-parameters

I'm wondering how to correctly route a default controller/action when the url is trailed by a named arg.

I.E.: I want to route `http://www.server.com/mode:full` to `http://www.server.com/users/index/mode:full`

I tried `Router::connect ('/:mode', array('controller'=> 'users', 'action'=> 'index'));` but it's not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for that, it looks like it's independant from CakePHP.
In fact this is Apache on Windows that recognise ':' as a logical drive and thus simply don't route the correct (at least the intended) URL.